# New features you would like to avail in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What are the new features you would like to avail in ASP.NET MVC in the future releases?

I Would say

1) A separate view engine for ASP.NET MVC instead of current WebForm view engine.
2) Asynchronous Controller Actions.
3) Subcontrollers / Partial Requests.

Answer (score 4):

yeah finding good documentation is the hurting factor at the moment.  I keep finding solutions which worked 2 months ago (Not helpful with current beta version)
But hey i'm really loving the push it has given me to embrace jquery and ajax.

I'm currently trying to figure out how to render a partial view inside of the controller - not having any luck either!

Answer (score 3):

Stop dropping new code - start dropping better documentation. :)  Oh and prescriptive guidance that uses EF rather than LINQ to SQL would also be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I would agree that better documentation would be great! I'm figuring everything out through trial and error, but I would like some guidance around how certain things should be done.

Subcontrollers would also be high on my list.

I actually hope they don't add too much more. Having control over my HTML and the ability to use jQuery without all of the "Control.ClientID" and ViewState mess is nice, I'd hate to see them mess it up by adding too many features.

Answer (score 1):

good documentation .. better support for server components ..

Answer (score 1):

Proper caching of subcontrollers / partial views.